# Как добавить блок перед определенным блоком?

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка

```html
<p>...</p>
...какие угодно теги и текст...
<h2>1</h2>
.....
<h3>1.1</h3>
.....
<h3>1.2</h3>
.....
<h2>2</h2>
....
<h3>2.1</h3>

и тд.
```

Мне нужно перед первым `<h2>` добавить блок с id="test"

Первый `<h2>` я нашел так:

```
let first_h2 = $('.blog-post').find('h2')[0];
```

Затем попробовал сделать так:

```
$(first_h2).prepend('<div id="test"></div>');
```

Но блок новый получился дочерним h2, а мне нужно чтобы он шел перед этим h2

Буду благодарен  за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
let first_h2 = document.querySelector('h2');
first_h2.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', '<div id="test">test</div>');
```

```html
<p>...</p>
<h2>1</h2>
<h3>1.1</h3>
<h3>1.2</h3>
<h2>2</h2>
<h3>2.1</h3>
```